# How to call some data from Python model in js code in Odoo?

Tags: odoo

In Odoo 10 I have the Python model like

```
class SubprogramPassport(models.AbstractModel):
_name = "energy.saving.program.subprogram.passport"
```

Also I have view file and "script" tag inside this one where I define my js code.
How to call some data from Python model in js code?

Comment: Can you show same line of your js code, where you want to load the data?

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of calling python model from js

```
var model = new Model('custom.model');
    model.call('custom_functions',
     [{
     active_id: this.selected_event_id || '',//example params
     filter: pyeval.sync_eval_domains_and_contexts({
            domains: search.domains,
            contexts: search.contexts,
            group_by_seq: search.groupbys || [],
        }),
     }])
```